# Shape of a distribution as a feature

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, statistics, algorithms

How can I use the shape of a distribution as a feature in machine learning ? Do I use something like the standard deviation ?

Comment: You can build a model involving a parametric or non-parametric distribution and apply Bayesian methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this distribution is row specific (each sample has a different associated distribution) or category specific this is not a bad approach to encode more information in your features. It's unclear how you have these distributions, are there empirical samples or do you have a parameterized distribution? A few approaches you could take to encoding this could be:

- Fit a distribution family (or if you have one already) and use the location/shape/scale parameters as features
- Add a few moments and other statistics of the distribution
- Or similarly take a few percentiles

Depending on the parameterization of the distribution, the first might be less direct but it should be easy to test.

Comment: So if I have two columns of data called Column A and B. What are the quantifiable statistical values or parameters that I can use  to determine if the columns A and B are similar or different in the values they represent ?

Comment: If you have numerical values in A and B and you believe the relationship between those matter for your task, that is already what models attempt to learn right? You could do all kinds of transformations but it will likely not do much better than that if you are using non-linear models like tree ensembles or neural networks

Comment: Ok. It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **shape of distribution** as augmented features (extra columns) when your records (ie each row of the table) contains a number of homogeneous values that form a population. Otherwise, the shape of the whole training dataset does not help in differentiating the data points from each other.

You can use mean and std as well as other parameters that define a statistical dustribution (depends which distribution you try to fit on your data).